# Escribir en console.log HttpStatus

Tags: angular, rest, http

Tengo una llamada http de un servicio backend que funciona correctamente, además este servicio backend devuelve un `ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK)` o por contra un `ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)`, pero me gustaría pintar el estatus de respuesta en consola, ¿me indican la sintaxis idónea?
Pego mi código:
Servicio:

```
  borrarInforme(): Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.baseURL + '/borrarInforme'}`, '').pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

    guardarInforme(): Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {
    console.log("entro en el metodo para guardar informe");
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.baseURL + '/guardarInforme'}`, '').pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    alert('Ha ocurrido un error abre inspeccion para comprobarlo')
    if (error.status === 0) {
      console.error(`Ha ocurrido un error: ${error.error}`)
    } else {
      console.error(`error en el backend ${error.status}. el error de la respuesta es: ${error.error}`);
    }
    return throwError(
      () => 'Algo no ha salido bien'
    );
  }
```

A continuación el componente que se suscribe a las respuesta de la llamada como se puede ver he intentado indicarle el tipo a la respuesta pero me indica que es null (response imprime null) por lo que entiendo que el problema esta en el servicio no estando correctamente estructurado el método:

```
  confirmarOk() {
    this.servicio.guardarInforme().subscribe(
      (response: HttpResponse<string>) => console.log(response.status)
    );
    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
  cancelar() {
    this.servicio.borrarInforme().subscribe(
      response => console.log(response)
    );
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

A continuación pego el método del controlador:

```
@PostMapping(/guardarInforme)
public ResponseEntity<String> guardarInforme(){
if(this.servicioReportingApp.guardarPDF()){
return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

}
@PostMapping(/borrarInforme)
public ResponseEntity<String> borrarInforme(){
if(this.servicioReportingApp.borrarPDF()){
return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es null, response.status o response?

Comment: response es null

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código de handleError?

Comment: Lo añado pero el flujo no entra en ese método

Comment: Estaba pensando que quizá hubiese un error y que `handleError` no devolviese nada, pero no es el caso por lo que veo... no se me ocurre por qué obtienes un null ahí, ¿has probado a depurarlo o a añadirle en el pipe un `tap(console.log)`?.

Comment: Añado los metodos del controlador por si puede servir para aclarar la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo una hipótesis:

Angular por defecto deja la respuesta a `null` cuando todo ha ido bien (HTTP 2XX) pero la respuesta está vacía.

Por tanto, deberías obtener un objeto HttpResponse si explícitamente lo pides:

```
return this.httpClient.post<any>(
     `${this.baseURL}/borrarInforme`,
     '',
     {observe: "response"}
).pipe (...)
```

Comment: efectivamente, ahora si saca por pantalla el estatus de respuesta, gracias